# Google IAP Public Keys Expiry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, public-key-encryption, google-identity, google-iap

[This page](https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key) provides public keys to decrypt headers from Google's Identity Aware Proxy. Making a request to the page provides its own set of headers, one of which is `Expires` (it contains a datetime).

What does the expiration date actually mean? I have noticed it fluctuating occasionally, and have not noticed the public keys changing at the expiry time.

I have read about [Securing Your App With Signed Headers](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto), and it goes over how to fetch the keys after every key ID mismatch, but I am looking to make a more efficient cache that can fetch the keys less often based on the expiry time.

Here are all the headers from the public keys page:

```
Accept-Ranges →bytes
Age →1358
Alt-Svc →quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"
Cache-Control →public, max-age=3000
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →519
Content-Type →text/html
Date →Thu, 29 Jun 2017 14:46:55 GMT
Expires →Thu, 29 Jun 2017 15:36:55 GMT
Last-Modified →Thu, 29 Jun 2017 04:46:21 GMT
Server →sffe
Vary →Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Expires` header controls [how long HTTP caches are supposed to hold onto that page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires). We didn't bother giving Google's content-serving infrastructure any special instructions for the keyfile, so whatever you're seeing there is the default value.

Is there a reason the "refresh the keyfile on lookup failure" approach isn't a good fit for your application? I'm not sure you'll be able to do any better than that, since:

- Unless there's a bug or problem, you should never get a key lookup failure.
- Even if you did have some scheduled key fetch, it'd probably still be advisable to refresh the keyfile on lookup failure as a fail-safe.

We don't *currently* rotate the keys super-frequently, though that could change in the future (which is why we don't publish the rotation interval), so it shouldn't be a significant source of load. Are you observing that refreshing the keys is impacting you?

--Matthew, Google Cloud IAP engineer

Comment: Thank you for the info! This detail is neither impacting or expected to impact my app, but I wanted to consider all possible angles of approaching the problem (and it looks like I will go ahead with following the sample in the article).